# How to replace slash with a backslash followed by slash in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

As titled.
Example:
from

```js
const str = 'a/b c/d';
```

to

```js
'a\/b c\/d'
```

The followings all fails to produce the correct answer

```js
str.replace(/\//g, '\\/');   // 'a\\/b c\\/d'
str.replace(/\//g, '\\\/');  // 'a\\/b c\\/d'
str.replace(/\//g, '\');     // syntax error
str.replace(/\//g, '\//');   // 'a//b c//d'
str.split('/').join('\\\/'); // 'a\\/b c\\/d'
```

Escape parsing seems to be quite inconsistent. I'm not sure how to deal with it.

Thank you.

Comment: `'a/b c/d'.replace(/\//g, "\\/")`

Comment: 3 of those 5 options [work as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/v4ytg5er/) -> Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Maybe it works in browser, which I didn't try. The results are from node v12.10.0. I stated in the tag

Comment: There's nothing in your script that wouldn't work in any version of a browser or node. They will also work in the old IE. [node example](https://ideone.com/zn0x6C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out if I code it in a file and run the file it works.

It's peculiar that if I run directly in node repl, it doesn't work.

In case you want to try, use either the console on the right hand side of [Repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/nodejs), or type node in your local machine, then type in

```js
'a/b c/d'.replace(/\//g, '\\\/');
```

You'll get the same incorrect result as I do.

Would appreciate if anyone knows why they differ.

Comment: _"It's peculiar that if I run directly in node repl, it doesn't work."_ - Which should have been part of the question and the [mcve] in it...

Comment: https://old.reddit.com/r/node/comments/3b5yja/how_to_escape_a_backslash/

Comment: Should I apologize for expecting node.js to be consistent?

Answer (score 0):

The last one will work if you just remove one backslash:

```
str.split('/').join('\\/'); // 'a\/b c\/d'
```

This is also a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gpwsn81y/1/

Hope this helps.